# How can I add meta element before my link element in my head

Tags: javascript, meta-tags, head

This is the code I currently have:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.setAttribute("charset","UTF-8");

head.insertBefore(meta,head.childNodes[1]);
```

It displays TypeError: head.childNodes is undefined.

Comment: Why are you trying to use JavaScript to change the encoding that the browser thinks the document is? The encoding isn't going to change, so why isn't the correct encoding specified directly in the document (and the HTTP headers).

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList, not a single element. The clue is that `Elements` is *plural*.

Put the first item off it with `[0]` or just use `document.head`.